# How to pass parameters to windows service via ManagementObject and InvokeMethod()

Tags: c#

Depending on the state, necessary to call the start of the windows service with parameters. The call used ManagementObject and InvokeMethod.
Is it possible to pass parameters into the service Onstart() method?

```
_sr.InvokeMethod("StartService", "Some Parameters"); --> 

protected override   void OnStart(string[] args)
 {
  args // <-catch here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can with `ManagmentObject`, however you probably can with [ServiceController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller?view=netframework-4.7.2) Class

[ServiceController.Start Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.start?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_ServiceProcess_ServiceController_Start_System_String___)

> Starts a service, passing the specified arguments.

```
ServiceController sc  = new ServiceController();
sc.ServiceName = "Alerter";
Console.WriteLine("The Alerter service status is currently set to {0}", 
                   sc.Status.ToString());

if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
{
   // Start the service if the current status is stopped.

   Console.WriteLine("Starting the Alerter service...");
   try 
   {
      // Start the service, and wait until its status is "Running".
      sc.Start(new []{"args","here","Yehaa");
      sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);

      // Display the current service status.
      Console.WriteLine("The Alerter service status is now set to {0}.", 
                         sc.Status.ToString());
   }
   catch (InvalidOperationException)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Could not start the Alerter service.");
   }
}
```

**Service**

public partial class MyService : ServiceBase
    {

```
    public MyService(uint port)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // This method gets called with `sc start`
    // and can be used to override arguments during startup
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        // Do stuff with args
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank  you. I know that the solution is a crutch, through "InvokeMethod("Change", "Some Parameters")" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/change-method-in-class-win32-service

Comment: @iSarzhan what do you mean

Comment: For my Task(It's enough), I change "PathName" via Change Method with the command line, then I catch these parameters in args [] for Main(string[] args).